# How to enable ssh root access on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh, root

I´d like to enable the `ssh` root access on Ubuntu 14.04. Editing the `/etc/ssh_config` (PermitRootLogin yes) didn't affect anything.

Answer (score 216):

Simply adding a password for root is not enough for Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

You also need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and comment out the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Just below it, add the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then restart SSH:

```
service ssh reload
```

---

For Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64) `PermitRootLogin without-password` has been replaced by `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`.

Comment: When doing this via ssh, `service ssh reload` is useful.

Comment: I was running Ubuntu on VM, however I don't know these changes didn't work till i restarted VM once (may be i need to stop/start network services in addition to above steps however I'm not sure).

Comment: I have to do `PermitRootLogin yes` because I had plain password

Comment: If doing this while ssh or scp tells you "Permission denied, please try again" in another window, quit and retry that ssh (or scp) instead of just re-typing in the password.

Comment: If I ever lose this key would I be able to regain access to this instance again? if I host my service on AWS ec2 or linnode would they be able to do something on a lost-key situation?

Comment: Once you copy your ssh key using `ssh-copy-id` or another method, you can uncomment `PermitRootLogin without-password` and comment out your new `PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: Also don't forget to check if root is mentioned in sshd_config: AllowUsers root

Comment: Mine doesn't have either line - AllowUsers nor PermitRootLogin.  So I added both.  Did `service ssh reload` and `service ssh restart` on the server.  Yet from the workstation when I do `ssh root@servername` it still prompts for password then says Permission Denied.

Comment: comment out or delete the line `PasswordAuthentication no`, if you want to login with ssh with password.

Answer (score 39):

You need to setup a password for the root account and then it will work.

```
sudo passwd
```

Enter same password twice.

P.S. After modifying /etc/ssh/sshd_config don't forget to reload the openssh server.

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

Comment: This will work; but to the OP: think twice before doing it. If you still do, and your PC is on the internet, consider adding `fail2ban` to the system. (This comment is related to enabling root login via ssh; having or not a local password for root is just a matter of taste).

Answer (score 30):

With Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

Set the password

`sudo passwd`

### Changes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Change PermitRootLogin

`PermitRootLogin yes`

You may also have to check value of PasswordAuthentication. If it is set to no then set to yes

`PasswordAuthentication yes`

Then restart SSH:

`service ssh restart`

Comment: This is the only complete answer. Other answers are missing some part.

Comment: Except mine does not have this line.  Adding it doesn't make it work.

Comment: OMG, yes!! Thank you! `PasswordAuthentication` was the missing link

Comment: I purged openssh-service and openssh-client on both systems ( Kali Linux and Ubuntu 18 ), reinstalled them, applied this answer and everytihng worked perfectly.

Comment: In my sshd_config, since  it has "UsePam yes", and a line "DenyGroups root",  besides all above actions, I need to remove the "root" for DenyGroups as well to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

For 14.04 you would have to comment below line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#StrictModes yes
```

Comment: Instead of disabling file mode checking, it would be better to ensure, that `/root/.ssh` and the files therein are not readable by any other user than root.

Answer (score -1):

For me, none of these steps worked, I've even tried something I wouldn't ever try for something else then a toy vm: `PermitRootLogin without-password`

The only thing that worked for me was disabling the PAM module for this:

```
UsePAM no
```

This option is normally at the very end of the file. To be honest, I don't know the real drawbacks of this, but since you're not supposed to allow root login online, I guess it's okay for a private dev-vm.

Nevertheless, set a strong password, always. Nope this is not an exception. Not even *only this time*...

Comment: `PermitRootLogin without-password` doesn't mean the root user gets to log in without authentication. It means the root user isn't allowed to log in with a password. Instead, the root user must log in utilizing RSA keys, which is more secure.

Comment: @Craig the problem I'm referring to is not that root would then need to use RSA SSH-Keys. The problem is that root is a user everyone knocking on the door of your SSH-Server knows exists. Which is not a good thing in my opinion. But feel free to let root login via SSH, but as you said, at least make sure it's using keys to do so!

Comment: You said you wouldn't try `PermitRootLogin without-password` for anything but a toy VM. That is what you use to disable password authentication for root, so that the only way root can logon is using RSA keys. You did not state that you tried that option *with* RSA keys. If you tried that option without keys, there's no way it could succeed. If you use `PermitRootLogin without-password`, then you cannot log on using password authentication at all, not with a strong password, not with a blank password, not at all.