# Cannot ssh as root to my virtual machine

Tags: ssh, root

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine to which I can ping perfectly from my host.

I created a root password and I can use it normally too. I also changed the ssh-conf file such that root login is permitted as below and the guest OS is re-started multiple times in the mean while:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

But even then I cannot cannot to it via "plink" (putty link) from the host machine. I tried simple ssh even that does not work. Note that plink I started in a dos window but ssh I tried using cygwin.

```
ssh root@10.122.1.100
root@10.122.1.100's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@10.122.1.100's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@10.122.1.100's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

And the /var/log/auth.log indicates the following ...

```
Jan 20 18:24:31 osboxes sshd[2735]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<HOST>  user=root
Jan 20 18:24:34 osboxes sshd[2735]: Failed password for root from 10.122.0.55 port 51989 ssh2
Jan 20 18:34:49 osboxes sshd[2749]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<HOST>  user=root
Jan 20 18:34:51 osboxes sshd[2749]: Failed password for root from 10.122.0.55 port 52256 ssh2
Jan 20 18:35:02 osboxes sshd[2749]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 10.122.0.55 port 52256 ssh2]
Jan 20 18:35:02 osboxes sshd[2749]: Connection closed by 10.122.0.55 [preauth]
Jan 20 18:35:02 osboxes sshd[2749]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<HOST>  user=root
```

I replaced the host address with  in the above log for this post.

Does any of you know what am I still missing ?

Many thanks,

Prakash

Comment: Is the VM running inside VirtualBox / VMware with "NAT" style networking, or is it connected direct to the network through a Bridged interface or similar?

Comment: May be I am noob or we are missing something ,  why port showing `  in Failed password for root from 10.122.0.55 port 51989 ssh2 `  as port 51989 ?

Comment: how did you create root password?

Comment: @raja this is remote port, not local from the `sshd` point of view. This is the port where the client `bind()`, not the server `listen()`ing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable ssh root access on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04) (see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04#469147))

Answer (score 1):

Thank your for your answers.

The answer is indeed simple because I seem to have edited ssh-config file instead of ssh**d**-config to enable root login. And after editing the file it seems to solve the issue.

Many thanks for your time

Prakash