# Ubuntu Lamp Server Setup Public IP Connection Issue

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp, ip

New to Linux OS and trying to setup a local server. At first, I didn't want to actually serve websites publicly, only locally for testing purposes. I am following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04).

I started with local IP 127.0.0.1 and entered:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1
```

It asked for a password. I entered my root password but it says "Permission denied". I also tried "password" and just hitting enter. None of this worked. In fact, just hitting "enter" gave me "Permission denied (publickey,password). I got the same results using my public IP.

I am tethering off a cell phone hotspot because the ISPs where I live, quite frankly, suck and limit bandwidth so this is my only option.

I want to keep my testing server private but if it's not possible, then public is ok.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and already have LAMP stack installed and it seems to run just fine, but I know I didn't do it right.

What am I doing wrong?

Help and guidance appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have a root access? This is not common in Ubuntu. Can you login as root in local terminal or authenticate successfully in `su` command?

Comment: You probably didn't have a ssh root access. Try to ssh with the user name that you have provided while installing Ubuntu like, ssh username@127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I did not have root access as suggested.

I figured it out by following [this Q&A.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04/469147)