# access denied in honeydrive when try to root ssh

Tags: ssh

Permission is denied when I try to `ssh root@10.0.2.15` in the command line .I tried honeydrive for the password ,that's the default password in honeydrive,it didn't work .
I'm trying to run kippo honeypot so I tried kippo's default password which 123456 but that didn't work too .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does it work when you try to log in as honeydrive?
It's probably disabled to log in as root - check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for PermitRootLogin setting. See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04) for details.